# How can I append a bunch of numbered list to a ul?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is what I have, which results in an error:

```
for (var x = 0; x < 10; x++){
    $('.wrapper ul').append('<li>Root Option 'x'</li>');
};
```

Comment: And the error would be..?

Comment: I recommend to read the [MDN JavaScript Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide) to learn the JS basics (string concatenation is a basic operation).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You missed the `+` operator when concatenating `x`

```
for (var x = 0; x < 10; x++){
    $('.wrapper ul').append('<li>Root Option ' + x + '</li>');
};
```

Comment: Sweet, I thought it was something simple.

Answer (score 1):

You are not concatenating the strings. Use this instead:

```
for (var x = 0; x < 10; x++){
    $('.wrapper ul').append('<li>Root Option ' + x + '</li>');
}
```

Take a look at this [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Description)

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var x = 0; x < 10; x++){
    $('.wrapper ul').append('<li>Root Option '+x+'</li>');
};
```

concatenation was not correct

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var x = 0; x < 10; x++){
    $('.wrapper ul').append($('<li>', {html: 'Root Option ' + x}));
} // just for fanciness ^_^
```